# Sequence of polynomials converging uniformly on unit circle converges uniformly to a holomorphic function on compact sets of the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been trying to solve the following question without success:

Suppose $p_{n}$ is a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly on the unit circle to a function $p$. Show that  $p_{n}$ convergence uniformly on all compact subsets of the unit disk to a holomorphic function.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: By "unit sphere", the unit circle $\{z:\lvert z\rvert = 1\}$ is meant?

Comment: Yes. For some reason the word circle momentarily disappeared from my mind..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the maximum principle,

$$\sup_{\lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1} \lvert p_n(z) - p_m(z)\rvert = \sup_{\lvert z\rvert =1} \lvert p_n(z) - p_m(z)\rvert.$$

Thus if a sequence of polynomials converges uniformly on the boundary $\partial\Omega$ of a bounded domain $\Omega$, it does in fact converge uniformly on $\overline{\Omega}$ (that holds more generally for functions continuous on $\overline{\Omega}$ and holomorphic in $\Omega$).

The holomorphicity of the limit function follows for example by Morera's theorem.

Comment: Lovely. Thanks!